# FancySelect box: click event not working when I click the fancySelect box

Tags: jquery

For updating the select box I am using the following code its work correctly. like this is there any other way to handle click event?

```
$('select').fancySelect().on( 'change.fs',function(e){
console.log('change made');
});
```

I am trying the following code for click event but event doesn't invoked..

```
var fancy=$('#myFancySelect');
   fancy.fancySelect();
   fancy.on('click.fs',function(){
   $('#myOuterDiv').css('border','0');                      
});
```

Kindly help me..

Comment: `$('select').on('click', function () { $(this).trigger('change.fs'); });` https://github.com/octopuscreative/fancyselect

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i try the above code,but unfortunately there is no changes has made.. I think normal click event doesn't invoked.. kindly help me..

Comment: It's hard to help you with what you've provided. Show us more of your code. Where's the `click` event handler?

Comment: Add the code to your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

I would use what you are currently using or alternativly this:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
    console.log('change made');
});
```

But you should look into jQuery native optons:

1. [Change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
2. [Select](http://api.jquery.com/select/)
3. [Click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)